# Loop through two Array in JavaScript and Constructing a function

Tags: javascript

I have Two Arrays in Javascript  as shown below :

```
Array one = new Array();
one.push(20061001);
one.push(20061002);
one.push(20061003);
one.push(20061120);


Array two = new Array();
two.push(3.0);
two.push(3.1);
two.push(3.2);
two.push(3.3);
```

Now Some how i need to loop through this Array and construct a function as shown

```
function NoisyData() {
return "" + 
"Date,A\n" +
"20061001,3.0\n" +
"20061002,3.1\n" +
"20061003,3.2\n" +
"20061120,4.0\n" ;
}
```

**Please help me as how to do this ??**

Comment: Your arrays have (certainly) the same size?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var one = new Array();
one.push(20061001);
one.push(20061002);
one.push(20061003);
one.push(20061120);


var two = new Array();
two.push('3.0');
two.push('3.1');
two.push('3.2');
two.push('3.3');



function NoisyData() {

    var result = "Date,A\n";
    for(var i = 0; i < one.length;i++){

        result += one[i] + "," + two[i] + "\n"; 

    }

    return result;

}

alert(NoisyData());
```

Comment: As an aside, the Array initialisation can be done as:
    var one = [20061001, 20061002, 20061003, 20061120];
    var two = [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3];

Comment: Yeah, but we'd need to quote the 3.0 to get it to spit out as 3.0 instead of 3. Anyway, I tried to keep as much of the original in tact as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
function NoisyData() {
  var txt = "Date,A\n" 
  for (var i=0, n=one.length;i<n;i++) {
    txt += one[i]+","+two[i]+"\n"
  }
  return txt
}
```

UPDATE based on [KooiInc's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483338/loop-through-two-array-in-javascript-and-constructing-a-function/5483746#5483746):

```
<script>
var one = [20061001,20061002,20061003,20061120]
  , two = [3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3]
  , combined = function(res,two){
       var i = one.length;
       while(i--){
          res[i]+=','+two[i].toPrecision(2);
       }
       res.splice(0,0,'Date,A');
       return res.join('\n')
    }(one.slice(0),two); 
alert(combined);
</script>
```

Instead of one.slice(0) one.clone() can be implemented as
    `Array.prototype.clone = function() { return this.slice(0); }`

or just pass *one* itself instead if it is OK to modify the original array

Comment: Is the logic here that it doesn't have to check the length of one each iteration?

Comment: @Caterham Yes, exactly. Since I do not know how long these arrays might become, or even if they are normal arrays (could be DOM nodes or something) I often make sure I have the fastest comparison by storing the (hopefully immutable) length

Comment: @mplungjan please note that `clone` is not a native Array method. Is it really necessary to clone the original array?

Comment: @KooiInc Please see update. I did not want to modify the original array

Comment: @mplungjan: but in the original anonymous function the arrays aren't modified, it's only reading the element values of Arrays one and two.

Comment: @KooiInc I know, but I saved an array definition (`res=`) by passing in a new copy of the first array or passing in the original first array. We were having a test to see how short a function we could write, no? And mine also did not need to reverse :)

Answer (score 1):

The faster way for long array is :

```
var one = new Array();
one.push(20061001);
one.push(20061002);
one.push(20061003);
one.push(20061120);
var two = new Array();
two.push(3.0);
two.push(3.1);
two.push(3.2);
two.push(3.3);
function NoisyData() {
var ret = [];
ret.push("Date,A");
for (var i=0;i<one.length;i++){
ret.push(one[i]+','+two[i]);
}
 return ret.join('\n');
}
alert(NoisyData());
```

Comment: +1 for the push and join, but should we not also store the length, like I did? Also I would do `var ret = ["Date,A"];`

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be a lot shorter. You can't type variables (like `Array one`) in javascript. To declare an Array most of the time an [Array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Literals) is sufficient.
*If your arrays have the same length*, you can use the code hereby to combine them into the string you need:

```
var one = [20061001,20061002,20061003,20061120]
  , two = [3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3]
  , combine = function(a1,a2){
       var i = -1, len = a1.length, res = ['Date,A'];
       while(++i < len){
          res.push(a1[i]+','+a2[i].toPrecision(2));
       }
       return res.join('\n');
    }(one,two);
```

Try it @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jdn6U/

Comment: Why reverse? Only to save an assignment? And you lose the .0 in the first array item of two if you do not quote it (hmm, fixed in the fiddle in a fun way)

Comment: +1 for a clever way - See mine, I shortened it even more, I use clone to not mess with the original array

Comment: @mplungjan reverse, because the array is iterated reversed (from `one.length` to 0). But not really necessary, so updated the fiddle